# Puppet 4 - get a list of all the slaves connected

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

How can I get a list of all the slaves that connect to the puppet master in Puppet 4? I used to be able to get a look at the /var/lib/puppet/reports folder but with Puppet 4; I'm unable to find it that directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That would be in `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/reports` by default or whatever you have set `reportdir` to.
But you also must first enable reporting on the agents.
See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/reporting_about.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get all nodes from puppetdb if you have it installed:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/2.3/api/query/v3/nodes.html